# VBA How can Replace function read arguments from predefined list/file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that will replace in cells words listed in a function or maybe in outside file. I'm trying to declare a string but with no effect.
I have it working by having this line copied many times:

`Cells(g, h).Replace What:="BadWord", Replacement:=""`

I want to use only one time this line and instead of "BadWord" use for example `Badwords` as a list of all of the words i need to remove from cells.

```
' This is what i use now and is working":
For g = 2 To Rows() 
h = 4
Cells(g, h).Replace What:="BadWord1", Replacement:=""
Cells(g, h).Replace What:="BadWord2", Replacement:=""
Cells(g, h).Replace What:="BadWord3", Replacement:=""

Next g



'What i tried with no result:

Dim BadWords() As String
BadWords = Split("BadWord1,BadWord2,BadWord3", ",")

For g = 2 To Rows() 
h = 4
Cells(g, h).Replace What:=BadWords, Replacement:=""

Next g
```

I've searched why it won't work but i did not found any clear answer or solution. Probably im using it wrong or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through cells, consider using `Replace` on the entire column. You do need to loop through elements of the array though, something like this:

```
Sub Bowdlerize()
    Dim BadWords()
    BadWords = Array("BadWord1", "BadWord2", "BadWord3")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(BadWords) To UBound(BadWords)
        Worksheets("MySheetName").Columns(4).Replace What:=BadWords(i), Replacement:=""
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That was really helpfull! i managed to combine it into something like this:
`For g = 2 To h
h = 4
Dim BW() As String
BW = Split("Value1,Value2,Value3", ",")
For b = LBound(BW) To UBound(BW)
Cells(g, h).Replace What:=BW(b), Replacement:=""
Next b

Next g`

I think i need to stay with looping for cells cause i have thousands of them and it helps me optimize the speed of macro.